# In Particle Physics what does the Rest Mass notation: 95$^{+9}_{−3}$ MeV/c$^2$ mean?

Tags: particle-physics, notation

On the Wikipedia page for the [Strange Quark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_quark), I came across the following notation for defining its mass:

95$^{+9}_{−3}$ MeV/c$^2$

Following the reference link brings me to this [page](https://pdglive.lbl.gov/DataBlock.action?node=Q123SM), which shows a range of published values for the Strange Quark rest mass. Does that mean the $^{+9}_{−3}$ format indicates the value range for the rest mass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the way the [evaluation of the error](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2021/listings/rpp2021-list-light-quarks.pdf) for the quark masses is given in the [particle data group](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/tables/rpp2019-sum-quarks.pdf), page 10 for the strange quark in the link.

[image: squark]

In the corresponding figure for the up quark there is the clarification:

> Values above of weighted average, error,
> and scale factor are based upon the data in
> this ideogram only. They are not neces-
> sarily the same as our ‘best’ values,
> obtained from a least-squares constrained fit
> utilizing measurements of other (related)
> quantities as additional information